# Can we now use the DSI cnnector?

Tags: display, screen, touchscreen, gpu, dsi

Now that the GPU source has been made open source, will we be able to use the DSI connector to power display panels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The DSI connector is data and control only, no power.

It's unlikely that you will ever be able to use anything other than the Raspberry Pi Foundation's display panel or its clones.  The Foundation's display panel has not yet been released.

Comment: Ahhh ok, that's a shame