# Are there already "official" DSI screens available?

Tags: dsi

Just looked [at the wiki](http://elinux.org/RPi_Screens#interfacing_to_Raw_LCD_panels)and read about the DSI connector but there are only phone screens listed and not any screen made for using with the pi.

Is there already a screen out there which uses the DSI connector without anything else (not like the buck/boost converter for the iPhone screen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update: Yes

The Raspberry Pi foundation [has announced](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/) that [The official Raspberry Pi touchscreen display](http://swag.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-7-inch-touchscreen-display) is now available.

If you want to use it with the older Model A or B Raspberry Pi's however, there are some issues. Although it seems to be *electronically* compatible, at least one Official Supplier (Farnell's [Element14](http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-78156)) website says that:

> the display will technically work with the Model A and Model B boards (connecting it to the DSI port on the Pi board), however the mounting holes on the back of the display will only line up with the newer board design (A+, B+ and Pi2).

So it is only *fully* compatible with:

> - Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
> - Raspberry Pi Model B+
> - Raspberry PI Model A+

Comment: looks great, personally i'd wished for a better resolution, but atleast something

Comment: The link to the "official Raspberry Pi touchscreen display" points out that:
"The display currently does not work with the older Raspberry Pi Model A or B, although there may be a software update to enable compatibility." - does anyone know if this has changed?

Comment: Any idea of the issues preventing the use on older Pis (I have a B with a damaged HDMI output - pin 4 shorted to ground - which I want to use on a Home Automation project and a touch-screen control would be useful).

Comment: Sorry, I know no more than we're all being told. Shame really that they aren't supporting old devices. Of course it's entirely possible that the reason it took so long to produce a screen was a fundamental issue with earlier pi's rather than the screens themselves, so it may have required the new Pi's to get them to work.

Comment: Ah, ha - seems like the reason it is not supported is that there are NO mounting holes on the older Pis - I found this mentioned on both an EBay [seller](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Official-7-Raspberry-Pi-Touchscreen-Display-Raspberry-Pi-2-Model-B-/181861983158?hash=item2a57d1a3b6) (seems a long-term listing so hopefully won't rot too quickly) and an official supplier Farnell's [Element14](http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-78156) site...

Comment: ...  Both say "The display will technically work with the Model A and Model B boards (connecting it to the DSI port on the Pi board), however the mounting holes on the back of the display will only line up with the newer board design (A+, B+ and Pi2)."

Comment: That's interesting, so if you are happy to mount the display independently of the model A or B it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

*[As of Sept 8/15 this answer is defunct, but I'll it around for anyone interested in the historical tidbits...]*

As [noted here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24376/5538) and at [the end here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=64041&hilit=dsi&start=250) that connector isn't good for much *except* potentially a proprietary screen from the Foundation, since there aren't any (public) drivers for it.

There are a few pics around of a demo screen ([[1]](http://raspi.tv/2014/raspberry-pi-official-7-inch-dsi-prototype-preview) [[2]](https://projects.drogon.net/)) that was on display by the Foundation (and Farnell?) at a convention last year, but after searching the Foundation's own blog (for "DSI"), where stuff like this is announced, it seems that screen is still not for sale.

Also at the end of that second Foundation forum there is a quick reference to EMI (electromagnetic interference) problems, so at this point it could turn out the whole thing is infeasible.

Comment: well, that is a bummer. But thank you for the information :)

Comment: For an international audience, ISO 8601 date format is better to use than US standard, i.e. 2015-09-08, since most people in the world read 9/8/15 as 9th August rather than September the 8th. ISO 8690 is unambiguous. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country